# swf banner hosted on domain A does not geturl when embedded on domain B

Tags: flash, crossdomain.xml, geturl

I want to host swf banner ads and allow others to embed them without them having to upload a copy of the swf to their webserver. The problem is the link on the swf, which doesn't work if the swf is embedded on a page on another domain.

So swf in  www.mydomain.com/banner and embedded on page www.mydomain.com/page.asp works, but www.mydomain.com/banner - www.otherdomain.com/page.asp doesn't load the target website when the banner is clicked.

I have tried adding a crossdomain.xml to mydomain.com but to no effect.

The action script for the link on the banner is very simple:

```
on (release) {
    getURL("http://www.site.com");
}
```

The swf is published as Flash player version 8, action script version 2

Comment: The solution is to add <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always"> and AllowScriptAccess="always" in the embed tag.